# Why Won't This Page Work in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I'm curious if anyone can help me figure out why this page won't work in Firefox or Chrome?  It seems to just keep refreshing.
https://easypaynet.adp.com/epn/Login.jsp

Comment: Unless you post code it's unlikely anyone will be able to answer your question.  You need to show what you have tried and not expect us to view source and look through code and a bunch of HTML

Answer (score 1):

The page actively redirects any user with chrome or firefox, there might be a redirect loop or something.

But the page also uses a self signed security certificate which will make most people skip the page.

If the page is yours, create one without the certificate and skip the permanent redirect.